# Как правильно сделать мультиязычность для rest api?

Tags: php, java, rest

Просьба дать пинка в нужную сторону или показать пример похожего использования!
Есть база данных в которую записываются товары, у товаров есть категория а у категории родительская категория
[image: Родительская категория]

[image: Категория]

[image: Товары]

В бд все товары добавлены на одном языке. Как сделать так что бы была возможность получить их с помощью restapi на нескольких языках?

Answer (score 1):

Перевод обычно хранится в отдельной таблице.

```
create table `language` (
  `id` int(12) not null auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(32) not null,
  `code` varchar(32) not null,
  primary key (`id`)
);

create table `goods` (
  `id` int(12) not null auto_increment,
  `category_id` int(12),
  primary key (`id`)
);

create table `goods_title` (
  `id` int(12) not null auto_increment,
  `good_id` int(12),
  `language_id` int(12),
  `title` varchar(1000),
  primary key (`id`),
  foreign key (good_id) references good (Id),
  foreign key (language_id) references language (Id)
);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну и будет примерно так:

```
language table
"1","ru","russian"
"2","en","english"
"3","it","italian"

goods table
"1","1"
"2","2"

goods_title table
"1","1","1","рубашка"
"2","1","2","shirt"
"3","1","3","camicia"
"4","2","1","джинсы"
"5","2","2","jeans"
```

В RestAPI следовательно надо добавить поддержку запроса по языку в зависимости от нужд. Можно возвращать как один язык по умолчанию, так и все языки в виде json набора `{..., title : { ru : "рубашка", en : "shirt", it : "camicia" }}`.

```
/actions/{id}
/actions/{lang}/{id}
```

---

Еще обычно данные справочников, когда есть иерархия, хранят в специальном виде (иерархические данные) и используют иерархические запросы (CTE иерархические запросы). Они сложнее, но зато позволяют не думать о вложеностях (а вдруг у вас будет 3-й уровень или даже 10-й). Пока может и не надо, но на всякий случай упоминаю их, если захотите переделать категории в одну таблицу. [Примеры можно глянуть тут](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-adjacency-list-tree/).

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте новое поле в каждую таблицу:

```
ru_title, en_title, de_title...
```